# Fill stroke color on the basis of percentage i.e. 80%, 70% or any one else

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, bezier

[image]

I have created a bezier path with gray stroke color. But I need to make overlay of orange color on the same path with orange color and based on the percentage of path to be filled like 70%, 80% or any other value

```
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width/2,y: view.frame.size.height), radius: CGFloat(25), startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), endAngle:CGFloat(0), clockwise: true)
    print(circlePath)
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [10 ,10]
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    let shapeLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer1.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer1.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer1.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    shapeLayer1.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer1.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer1)
```

Comment: What do you mean "based on the percentage of the path"? If the overlay is a solid color (with opacity value) and covers the entire path, what is the percentage a reference to? Do you mean "if the path has opacity X then the overlay should be opacity X * 0.8"? Or do you mean you need the overlay to run from path length 0 to path length 80%, instead of being a full overlay?

Answer (score 3):

```
    let completionPercentage = 60.0

    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width/2,y: view.frame.size.height), radius: CGFloat(25), startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), endAngle:CGFloat(0), clockwise: true)
    print(circlePath)
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [5 ,5]
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
    let shapeLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer1.path = circlePath.cgPath
    shapeLayer1.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer1.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    shapeLayer1.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer1.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    let angle = completionPercentage * 1.8

    let circlePath1 = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: view.frame.size.width/2,y: view.frame.size.height), radius: CGFloat(25), startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi), endAngle:CGFloat(((180 + angle)/180)*Double.pi), clockwise: true)
    print(circlePath1)
    let shapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer2.path = circlePath1.cgPath
    shapeLayer2.lineDashPattern = [5 ,5]
    shapeLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    shapeLayer2.lineWidth = 1.0
    let shapeLayer3 = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer3.path = circlePath1.cgPath
    shapeLayer3.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    shapeLayer3.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    shapeLayer3.lineWidth = 10
    shapeLayer3.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer1)
    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer3)
```

Output :-

[image]